# Using class to import- only working for last line

Tags: python, loops, class, import

trying to get my code to print out everything in the text file using my class, but it is only printing the last line.

Any ideas on how to get my loop working so it does every line? there are 3 lines and they are comma delimited.

```
Class Cars:
    def __init__(self,color, model, year):
            self.color = color
            self.model = model
            self.year = year
    def getcar:
        return '{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(self.color,self.model,self.year)

Text File:
Blue Corolla 2012
Green Civic 2011
Black CRV 2015

dataFile = open('carData.txt.txt')
for line in dataFile:
    lineData = line.split(',')
    color1 = int(lineData[0])
    model1 = float(lineData[1])
    year1 = float(lineData[2])

car_1= Cars.Cars(car1,color1,make1,year1)
car_2= Cars.Cars(car1,color1,make1,year1)
car_3= Cars.Cars(car1,color1,make1,year1)
car_4= Cars.Cars(car1,color1,make1,year1)
car_5= Cars.Cars(car1,color1,make1,year1)

print(car_1.getcar())
print(car_2.getcar())
print(car_3.getcar())
print(car_4.getcar())
print(car_5.getcar())

Output:
Black CRV 2015
Black CRV 2015
Black CRV 2015

Desired Output:
Blue Corolla 2012
Green Civic 2011
Black CRV 2015
```

Comment: You are assigning to variables for each line in the final, so only the last line will be saved at the end.  Consider appending to a list.

Comment: first off, thanks to the people who have taken time to respond. However, even when I append it to a list it seems I cannot index the list into the class objects so I am having trouble storing the values as separate objects. Is there a way to get it not just to print, but to be in the car_1, car_2 etc. objects so that I can call car_1 and have it contain all the variables of the class- but not be tied to the other values?

Comment: never mind figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop

```
for line in dataFile:
    lineData = line.split(',')
    color1 = int(lineData[0])
    model1 = float(lineData[1])
    year1 = float(lineData[2])
```

You extract the values of color, model, year by splitting the line you read but you are not saving these anywhere. So, they essentially "lost" except for the last line which remains even after you exit the for loop and that is why you get the same output.

Ideally, inside the for loop, you could save these values to an array or a list.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of variables every time you run your loop.

```
for line in dataFile:
    lineData = line.split(',')
    color1 = int(lineData[0])
    model1 = float(lineData[1])
    year1 = float(lineData[2])
```

This block of yours will always overwrite the value of your variables `color1`,`model1` and `year1` and as a result the last line is what you have in these variables when you finish processing your loop. There are multiple ways to fix it. One of them follows.

```
class Cars:
    def __init__(self,color, model, year):
            self.color = color
            self.model = model
            self.year = year
    def getcar(self):
        return '{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(self.color,self.model,self.year)

cars = []
dataFile = open('cars.txt')
for line in dataFile:
    lineData = line.split(' ')
    color1 = (lineData[0])
    make1 = (lineData[1])
    year1 = float(lineData[2])
    cars.append(Cars(color1,make1,year1))


for car in cars:
    print(car.getcar())
```

Here every time you iterate, read a line from your file, you read those values, create an object and add it to an existing list. Then you iterate on that list printing all the objects one by one.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code may provide you with a solution:

```
colors = []
models = []
years = []

dataFile = open('carData.txt')
for line in dataFile:
    lineData = line.split(',')
    colors.append(lineData[0])
    models.append(lineData[1])
    years.append(lineData[2])

for i in range(3):
    print(colors[i] + " " + models[i] + " " + years[i])
```

If you put your values from "carData.txt" into lists, you can then access them later to print them out in a desired format.